# MySQL Won't Source, then won't connect

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a text (.sql) file into a MySQL database on Windows 2008 R2, using localhost, but getting an odd error where the first letter of the database name is getting truncated. I first do 'show databases' to confirm I'm in and the strings are correct, then change to the target database, then run 'Load E:\MySQL\rosedestinationlog.sql;

To avoid any ambiguity, I am logging in as root.

That returns the weird error 1049 followed by the name of the database with the first character missing. If I then try to do anything else, such as running 'show databases' again, I get an error that the connection is lost. Exiting the CL and re-starting it allows me to re-connect, but with the same errors after that.

I've opened port 3006 in both directions to TCP. I can source some other files, but others hit the same errors. I can load these files without problem on a Mac. Below is the CL screen printout:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> mysql -u root -p;
Enter password: *******
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 61
Server version: 5.5.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| akhf_beta          |
| bank               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| rosecampdiary      |
| rosedestinationlog |
| roseflightprep     |
| ruredb             |
| test               |
+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use rosedestinationlog;
Database changed
mysql> source E:\MySQL\rosedestinationlog.sql;
ERROR:
Unknown command '\M'.
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'osedestinationlog.sql;'
mysql> show databases;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'osedestinationlog.sql;'
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're running:

```
mysql> source E:\MySQL\rosedestinationlog.sql;
```

It looks like the the backslash-M is being picked up by the program. Try putting the file path all in quotes e.g. something like:

```
mysql> source 'E:\MySQL\rosedestinationlog.sql';
```

Comment: This isn't working, but seems slightly promising. When quoting, I get a different error (22), 'Failed to open file <file name>', and the connection to MySQL was not broken.

Comment: Here's what worked: moving the source file out of the MySQL sub-directory, and issuing the Source command with normal syntax. MySQL seems to not like itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> use rosedestinationlog < source "E:\MySQL\rosedestinationlog.sql";
```

If your source `.sql` file contains statement to create database `'rosedestinationlog'`
    remove it and try it will work.

Comment: There is no such statement in the source file. Thanks for the suggestion.